# How to get the longitude and latitude value of the marker in google map v2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am working in google map v2. I just added one marker on the map. But I am not being able to get location from the marker. I have search a lot in google but didn't get proper answer. I just want to toast the longitude and latitude value of the marker. Can anyone suggest me anything?

My code:

```
double mylongitudey,mylatitudey;
String latilongi;
ImageView iv;
Button manual,proceed;

GoogleMap map;
LatLng mylat ;

String latlong;
Marker mymarker,marker;
boolean markerclicked;
double mylatitudeyd,mylongitudeyd;
String addstringaa;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 LocationManager lm;
  lm= (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  Toast.makeText(this,"Please select the destination by long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  LatLng mylat;

  final GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
  map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
  map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);


  map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);

  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
 // map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);


  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylat, 13));
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylat).title("You are Here"));

 markerclicked=false;
  //onMyLocationButtonClick();
  map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(markerclicked==false)
        {
         mymarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).title("Your Destination").draggable(true));
         markerclicked=true;
    }else{

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Marker Aready Set..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    }
});


  map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    LatLng mylatlong;
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mylongitudey = arg0.getLongitude();
        mylatitudey = arg0.getLatitude();
        mylatlong = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude());
        //sourcepoint=String.format(" ",mylat);
        marker= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylatlong).title("YOur Destination"));
//  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylat,1));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylatlong, 14));


    }
});
```

Comment: post your code then what you tried till now>..

Comment: @Manish Thanks for the reply..I have done as u have said

Answer (score 3):

Calling [`marker.getPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()) will return a [`LatLng`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) object which stores latitude and longitude.

```
Marker marker = <your initialization>;
LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
double latitude = latLng.latitude;
double longitude = latLng.longitude;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it is giving the current position rather than the marker postition

Comment: @android_newcomer you add the marker to your current position, what coordinates do you expect to get??

Comment: where should i add the marker to get the marker position...plz answer

Comment: @android_newcomer this answers the question you have asked. If you have a different question or your question have changed you should start a new one and describe it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            List<Address> detail = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(), 1);
            cityName = detail.get(0).getAddressLine(1);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

try

```
latitude = detail.get(0).getLatitude();
```

Comment: Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault()); create Geocoder object and try LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(detail.get(0).getLatitude(), detail.get(0).getLongitude()); this instead of city name nd set marker.setTitle(latLng2);

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.d("location"+marker.getPosition().longitude+" "+marker.getPosition().latitude);
```

probably this wil help...